# How would I move a div below another div and still have the top div have"position:fixed"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

So I am making a website for my web design business. I want to have the top div (header) to stay as-is but I want the img below to be below the "head" id and still function as a normal web-page.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpe0Lu2w/) in case you want to see the code run... You won;t see the imgs though... Sorry..

I have already tried setting the position on both things to "relative". But that doesn't work with the header.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.fontSize = "30px";
    document.getElementById("name").style.fontSize = "40px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "#f2f2f2";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.fontSize = "40px";
    document.getElementById("name").style.fontSize = "50px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

```css
#header {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid black;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav {
text-align: right;
padding: 0px 20px;
font-size: 40px;
transition: 0.2s;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

#name {
text-align: left;
padding: 0px 20px;
font-size: 50px;
transition: 0.2s;
font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
color: black;
}

#ourStatement {
font-size: 39.06px;
}

#skyLimit {
border-bottom: 1px;
}

#everything {
position: relative;
}

li a {
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#missionStatement {
text-align: center;
font-family: "Arial";
}

blockquote {
font-size: 31.25px;
border-left: 10px solid gray;
border-radius: 5px;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
} 

#schedule {
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 50px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

a:visited {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul id="name">
   <li><a href="#">DevWeb Web Development</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="everything">
  <div id="webInfo">
   <img src="imgs\personWebsite.png" alt="If you see this message please E-Mail the developer at oof" style="top: 50;">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="missionStatement">
   <p id="ourStatement"><u>Mission Statement</u></p> 
   <p style="font-size: 0.5px;">-</p>
   <blockquote>Our goal is to bring you the best customer service and web design that will ever meet your eyes. And we strive to bring you just that. Because when it comes to the front of your business, you want the best quality with the customer support that you need to keep it running. And that's the way that DevWeb Web Development does things.</blockquote>
  </div>
  <div id="wantWebsite">
   <img src="imgs\finger.png" alt="If you see this message please E-Mail the developer at oof" style="max-width: 100%;">
   <p id="schedule"><a href="#">Schedule <strong>YOUR</strong> appointment <strong>TODAY</strong></a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: I want to have the "header" id tag to stay fixed and the content below that to be below the "header" tag

Comment: So I believe you have answered your own question. Insert closing `</div>` tag where you want your `#header` to end everything that follows will be outside the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to read about tweeter's bootstrap and use it :
and For your current code try using this

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.fontSize = "30px";
    document.getElementById("name").style.fontSize = "40px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "#f2f2f2";
    document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementsByClassName("everything")[0].style.marginTop = "100px"; 

  } else if( document.body.scrollTop < 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 20 ) {

    document.getElementById("nav").style.fontSize = "40px";
    document.getElementById("name").style.fontSize = "50px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("header").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementsByClassName("everything")[0].style.marginTop = "0px"; 

  }
}
```

or Remove `position:relative;` from the header css

```
#header {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid black;
  left: 0;
/*  position: relative;*/
}
```

and 
instead of `#everything` it should be `.everything` as its a class

Use this

```
.everything {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 18%;
}
```

so your css together will be

```
 #header {
      background: white;
      color: black;
      text-align: center; 
      font-weight: bold; 
      position: fixed;
      top: 0; 
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 2.5px solid black;
      left: 0;
    /*  position: relative;*/
    }
.everything {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 18%;
    }
```

Comment: @DevinC. This is not a fully working solution. See output here: https://jsfiddle.net/wa0vtsn3/2/ Make sure you test this in full screen.

Comment: leme try again :)

Comment: try making (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) and (document.body.scrollTop < 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 20) 

do not forget to make changes in css ie: # header part and #everything to .everything

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative;` from `#header`. You have `position: fixed;` before that but you are cancelling it by declaring `relative` after. You want the position to be `fixed` on your header and the rest of your content default positioning. That will make the header stick to the top as you scroll past every else.

Comment: From what I've gathered, @DevinC wants the content below the header to be fully visible, not hidden by the fixed header at the top.

Comment: Thank you. But what I want to do is have all the content below to not be inside of the header. And what I mean by content is the img that I have right below the "header" tag

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the `margin-top` attribute of `#everything` to the height of `.header`. Since the height of the header varies, you can get the height and set `margin-top` accordingly programmatically like this:

```
var height = document.getElementById('header').getBoundingClientRect().height;
document.getElementsByClassName('everything')[0].setAttribute("style", "margin-top:"+height+"px");
```

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wa0vtsn3/1/